# Set inclusion relation ⊇ on power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am creating the set inclusion relation ⊇ from a power set, A. If my relation creates tuples with the following format, (x, y), will y ever be the empty set, {}?

Example: 
Set A = {x, y, z}

Power set of A, P(A) = {{}, {x}, {y}, {z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {y, z}, {x, y, z}}

Comment: what do you mean by will $1$ ever be included in the tuples? the power set of ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}$ will for sure include ${1}$

Comment: 1 is meant to represent the empty set. I updated the question to be more clear

Comment: The empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. If you are asking whether $\emptyset \supseteq \emptyset$, then the answer is yes. Every element of the righthand side (of which there are none) is also an element of the lefthand side. Such as statement is called "vacuously true".

Comment: Why bother with the 1-8 labelling? It is rather confusing. Just use the actual subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the empty set is a subset of every set. All tuples $(z,\emptyset)$ will be included including $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$

Comment: I got rid of the number labeling in my question, so you might want to reword your answer a little - very helpful answer for me though

Comment: @user2196424:  Thanks, done